# Can I multiplex a thermocouple (using a MPC507) without losing significant accuracy?

Tags: sensor, switches, analog, multiplexer, thermocouple

I would like to reduce the number of thermocouple to digital converters ([MAX31856](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/sensors-and-sensor-interface/MAX31856.html)) needed on my board for the sake of space. One approach that I have considered is multiplexing the eight different thermocouple inputs using a differential multiplexer ([MPC507](http://www.ti.com/product/MPC507/description)). Is this possible with thermocouple voltages (10s of milli volts) without significant measurement distortion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the thermocouple signals in copper on the PCB, then adding another small IC, one whose legs are at the same temperature as each other, is unlikely to damage the reading accuracy significantly.

A potential problem with the MPC507 is its high RDSon, 1300ohms typical, 1800 max over temperature. Being differential, that's typically 2600ohms out and back. Some thermocouple receivers pass a small current through the thermocouple to detect open sensors. However the 31856 can handle loop resistances of 5k or 40k when detecting O/C, and its input bias current is +/-4nA maximum, which will introduce an offset of max 10uV in 2.6kohm, max 0.25C for a K type.

It looks like you'll get away with it.

Comment: Would the [AD407](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/analog-devices-inc/ADG407BNZ/ADG407BNZ-ND/997724) would be a more appropriate general solution since it has a low R_on

Comment: MPC507 resistance is 'low enough' for the MAX31856. Looking at the data sheet, 1k of that comes from the series input protection resistor, which AD407 doesn't have. Do you want extra input protection? Are you feeling lucky punk? They have similar leakage currents (10nA in 507 could be best part of 1C error, 20nA in 406 is nothing due to lower resistance) and cost, who knows?

Answer (score 2):

I finally ordered parts, wired up the board, and verified that the AD407 works well with a MAX31856. The multiplexer can be introduced without noticeably reducing accuracy.

Comment: It looks as though you entered a comment in the answer box in error. You should delete this.

Comment: @Transistor - OP asked if X can be done without Y. They then answered their own question with "After testing, X can be done without Y". I think that counts as an answer, right? Though, some numbers would be nice.

Comment: OP had already accepted Neil's answer and posted the same information in a (now deleted) comment there. I'll give up on this one.